# Angular and code mirror

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, codemirror

I've been trying to add some features to a `javascript` tool, and I need to highlight a line in `codemirror`. I'm using `AngularJs`.
First I tried to follow a tutorial

```
function highlightLine(lineNumber) {

    //Line number is zero based index
    var actualLineNumber = lineNumber - 1;

    //Select editor loaded in the DOM
    var myEditor = $("#body_EditorSource .CodeMirror");

    //Write the item to the console window, for debugging
    console.log(myEditor);

    //Select the first item (zero index) just incase more than one found & get the CodeMirror JS object
    var codeMirrorEditor = myEditor[0].CodeMirror;

    //Write the item to the console window, for debugging
    console.log(myEditor[0].CodeMirror);

    //Set line CSS class to the line number & affecting the background of the line with the css class of line-error
    codeMirrorEditor.setLineClass(actualLineNumber, 'background', 'line-error');
}
```

But it doesn't work, doesn't detect the `myEditor var`... I've tried:

```
var myEditor = document.getElementById('codeMirrorDiv');
var myEditor = angular.element(document.querySelector((".codeMirrorDiv")));
```

and nothing. What does seem to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The function is called [`addLineClass`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addLineClass)

Comment: Yes, after i notice that stupid error a did this:

    //Line number is zero based index
    var actualLineNumber = lineNumber - 1;
    //Select editor loaded in the DOM
    var myEditor = angular.element(document.querySelector(("#codeMirrorDiv")));

    var codeMirrorEditor = myEditor[0].childNodes[0].CodeMirror;

    codeMirrorEditor.addlineClass(actualLineNumber, 'background', 'line-error');

still doenst work

Comment: Where exactly are you using this code, in a controller? Directive? And at what "time".

Comment: I'm using in a function of a controller when the user select a result scan it would show the var line highlight blue. 
show_result(){
...
setvalue() //fill the codemirror
setcursor() //set hte cursor
sethighlight(3) // just for testing, hihglihg line blue 
}

Comment: We need a little more context then, can you make a fiddle showing the problem? Because my guess is you are selecting it wrong. You should not use jquery in a controller, you should make a directive instead.

Comment: the thing is in the 

    codeMirrorEditor.addlineClass(actualLineNumber, 'background', 'line-error');

while debugging, codemirroreditor have the function in __proto__: Object, but why i'm not able to access it?

http://jsfiddle.net/utcsz/

Comment: hmm i did it but i dont know how.. setvalue now erases the class

Comment: Without seeing a fiddle, it's hard for me to help you further.